# Super nested tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm having to put together as an assingment an access database for a chain of hotels.
My dilemma is this the task requires multi step downs as you progress layers.

There are 19 hotels each with different number of floors
Each floor within different hotels has different areas 
Each of these areas then has elements within it
Finally each element has items associated with it.

The idea being you have multiple combo boxes on a form where you select the hotel which the gives the appropriate floors in the next cb. A floor is selected and the areas associated with that floor for the given hotel are listed and so in till the final cb gives the items.

I'm struggling as the tables all seem to need to be many is to many relationship wise and so can't see how to nest them or if this is even the best option.

Help please

Comment: Do you have any code we could look at?

Comment: It might help a bit if you explained exactly which part you were having trouble with. For example perhaps you'e having trouble  reacting to a change in a combo box? Or it could be writing a SQL statement that has more than one table or joining on more than one condition, etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble with knowing what info to put into the tables so that they can be linked. Hotel 1 has levels 1-5 as does hotel 2 but hotel 3 has levels 1-6. If that's all I would be fine but I need to specify the different areas that ate on each level for each hotel. For example hotel 1 has a restaurant on level 1 but the other hotels don't. So I need to be able to select hotel 1 then level 1 and then have the option to select restaurant whereas if hotel 2 or 3 were selected then level 1 restaurant should not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you have many-many relationships at all. Hotel table relates to floor table relates to areas table relates to elements table relates to items table.  But if you want to model many-many relationships use a linking table.

So hotel table withe hotelid as the PK and whatever other indfo you need in general about the hotel.  Floor table with a floorid and whatever other floor related information. The HotelFloor table that contains only the hotelid and floorid.

But you really only need that structure if the floor , area, etc structure will not be unique to the particular hotel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this.  To me, all of these relationships are one-to-many.

I think part of your confusion is that you are thinking of a Hotel Floor only in terms of one of its properties, namely the level.  So you think Hotel A has a level 1 Floor and Hotel B has a level 1 floor, therefore, a many-to-many relationship exists between floors and hotels.  This would be true if the only property a floor had was its level.  But as you've already stated, each floor of each hotel has its own set of areas.  So the level 1 floor of every hotel cannot be represented by a single record.

Instead of thinking of the floor in terms of its level, think of each floor as its own entity.  If you do this you realize that a hotel may have many floor entities, but each floor entity may only belong to one hotel.

A real-world example makes this crystal clear:

- You walk into the elevator in Hotel A and press 3.
- Your friend walks into the elevator in Hotel B and presses 3.

**If the many-to-many model were true, you and your friend would be standing side by side when you exit the elevator.**  Obviously that is not the case, so a one-to-many relationship makes sense.

For the same reason, all of the relationships in your example are one-to-many.  They may be modeled like so:

**Hotels**: (PK)HotelID, etc.
**Floors**: (PK)FloorID, (FK)HotelID, Level, etc.
**Areas**: (PK)AreaID, (FK)FloorID, etc.
**Elements**: (PK)ElementID, (FK)AreaID, etc.
**Items**: (PK)ItemID, (FK)ElementID, etc.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `Elements` and `Items` are not m:n; some of the other relationships may be 0..1:m ("zero-or-one-to many"). I love your real-world example, though :)

Comment: Good point.  Without knowing what `Elements` and `Items` actually represent, it's hard to say for sure.